# Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78) on ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless

Its been 5 months since I have started using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I could not use wifi because the chip on my laptop is not recognised by ubuntu 16.04 (Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)). I don't have any driver to use the wifi. How can I solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i scanned intel for info (https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) said kernel 4.6+ is needed ... hence maybe upgrading to a 4.6 kernel (or later) may help, support being http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/  note: i don't know your device, nor if this will help...

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, your device isn't supported until kernel version 4.6 and later. I believe that Ubuntu 16.04.3 runs 4.4.0-xx; confirm:

```
uname -r
```

You can install kernel version 4.10 with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

You probably also need newer firmware.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having a slew of issues (wireless, USB, etc) with a brand new 7th generation Intel NUC. The steps above fixed my issues. As of Jan 14th, 2018, running sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04 gave me Kernel 4.13.0-26, likely due to the Meltdown patches. As a result, I installed firmware linux-firmware_1.169.2_all.deb. No issues so far.

Comment: worked by just installing linux-generic-hwe-16.04

Thanks!